# Struts 2 Jquery Ajax Form submit filenotfound error

Tags: jquery, struts2, form-submit, ajaxform

I have a form on my jsp which looks like

`<s:form action="registerUser" theme="simple" name="AddUserForm" id="AddUserFormID" method="post">`

In my struts.xml I have made entry for the action "registerUser" and class name I have pointed to the proper java action class.  My result parameter in the xml is

`<result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="includeProperties">JSON</param>
            </result>`

I am submitting the form using this code

```
    `<s j:submit formIds="AddUserForm" value="Submit" indicator="indicator" button="true" />`
```

When I submit the form I can see the request going through but I get error "Jsp Processing error JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /pages/registerUser.jsp. "

Please help.

Comment: where you  have defined this registerUser.jsp?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I dont want the response on another jsp, It needs to come on same one. I dont have any such jsp, dont know how come its giving such error and trying to find it.

Comment: i am sure its taking some reference from some places.my suggestion is to use editor debug capabilities

Comment: This is a new module that I am developing so there are no such jsp created by me, plus if I change the action name it tries to find that name jsp and gives the same error

Comment: there is no attribute called id in struts taglib!!

Comment: I have used json and struts  together a lot, on such situations I was using some methods like getJSON("actionname",input,output) which will send the data to server and the response back, so  particular page submission was not needed.
May be you van try some thing like that...